# Google App Engine Flexible Environment creating too many VM instances

Tags: google-app-engine

I followed the **Quickstart for Node.js in the App Engine Flexible Environment** found at 
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

I deployed the hello-world node.js app using `gcloud preview app deploy`.
However, this simple command generated dozens of VM instances that I can see on the Developers Console. These instances are named gae-default-*timestamp-xywz*.
I manually deleted the instances on the console, and minutes later new ones were back, only stopping to create new ones when my resources quota is reached.

Has anyone out there seen anything like this and know how to fix the issue? Thanks!

Comment: I'm also having the same problem, how do you remove the sample app once you've deployed?

Answer (score 0):

For the existing instances, you need to shut down first before deleting them. And to fix the new instance spinning, you can use max_num_instances: THE NUMBER_AS_YOU_DESIRE (ex. [max_num_instances: 2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#services) for auto scale) in your app.yaml file.

Comment: Khalid, thanks for your answer. I added the max_num_instances to the yaml file. Also shutdown and deleted the instances, but they "magically" reappear after a few minutes - not sure how to get rid of them for good. I will be charged for resources I'm not even using.